# How to bring up Firebug debug consoles?

Tags: firefox, debug, firebug

[Everyone says you simply click the 'scripts' tab to bring up the debug console.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721809/debugging-jquery-with-firebug)

But I don't have that tab/window/pane. How do I bring it up?

Here's a screenshot of my Firefox 5 - I really don't have that window/pane! Can't figure out how to bring it up.

[image: Firefox screeenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was removed with FF4. You now have to download it:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/

Comment: I already had it installed, but like you said, it was an old version. Upgraded and it works now.